# MySQLdb working locally but no when deploying

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, mysql-python

I built an app using google app engine and cloud sql, I got a data-base server host through google.
when i connect to the data-base ,using MySQLdb package, the app is working fine.
When I try to Deploy the app, I get an internal server error. I found out that it is caused because
the connection to the data base failes . (the app works on deployment when I do not connect to the data base)
Does someone know what is causing the problem, and why I am unable to connect to the db when deploying the app ? thank you

```
# define a class MainPage which inherits from the class webapp2.RequestHandler
# The class displays the main page of our application
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # define the method get in our class MainPage - to handle http get requests
    # creates a response "Hello World!"
    def get(self):
        g.db_conn = MySQLdb.connect(
                                    host='the host ip num',
                                    user='my username',
                                    passwd='my password',
                                    db='the db name')
        cursor = g.db_conn.cursor()
        query = """ select * from manager107.air_crew """
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = str(cursor.fetchall())
        cursor.close()
        g.db_conn.close()        
        # the response will be in a text/plain format
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        # Add the text 'Hello World !' to the response
        self.response.write('Hello world!', rows)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
# -----------------------------------------
# programming language
# -----------------------------------------
runtime: python27

# -----------------------------------------
# python sub version
# -----------------------------------------
api_version: 1

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# threadsafe - to prevent collision between calls to the application
#              from different clients
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
threadsafe: true

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# handlers - define an application file for each URL we get
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
handlers:
- url: /
  script: helloworld.app

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: latest
```

these are the only files I have! please help

Comment: unix_socket=, is a mistake! it was not in the original code

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Comment: there is almost nothing in these data base, only experimental. when i get the question I will have a new one, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not connecting to Cloud SQL using the right way. In order to connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine you need to have a JSON file with they credentials of the Service Account that you are going to use and you must use the Cloud SQL connection name that you will be able to see in the Cloud Console UI.

All the steps needed as well as some samples can be found in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) and in the [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy) repository.

Comment: You are welcome! Let us know if you managed to make it work and please consider accepting the answer if that helped solving your issue :)

Comment: should i use the sqlalchemy or i can keep using MySQLdb ? I don't see any JSON in the link

Comment: In the GitHub link that I've attached in the answer, there are all the needed steps on how to connect. Regarding MySQLdb vs sqlalchemy I'd suggest you to use sqlalchemy first as you have an example on how to ahieve it already. Once you have your app up and running you can try to switch to MySQLdb.